# Webpack Not Resolving Tsconfig Paths in Subproject

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, next.js, monorepo

I have a project which is a monorepo, using NPM workspaces and TS project references to separate the components. The `frontend` workspace is a Next.js app, and it imports some types and utilities from the `shared` workspace. So far so good. Now, I wanted add the path alias `@customTypes/*: ["src/types/*"]` to the TSConfig of `shared` - but it appears that they aren't resolved during compilation; rather `shared/dist/filter.d.ts` literally has the statement `import { Filter } from "@customTypes/filter"` in it. There is also a `backend` workspace which is just compiled with TSC, and it works fine, the aliases in the referenced project are understood fine.
But when I build the frontend, Webpack (used by Next.js) fails to resolve the alias. I found [a Webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) that looked good, but it only resolves the aliases from the Webpack project's own TSConfig (and it must already be part of Next.js by default anyway, since I already have aliases in the frontend)

Manually adding each alias (re-mapped relative to the frontend, of course) to the webpack config just causes the same problem as the `../../../../../types/filter` imports that I'm trying to get rid of: move one file, have to update multiple references. I read about the notion of putting path aliases in a top-level TSConfig that all others inherit from, which would be okay since I don't have that many aliases, but I couldn't get it to work and it seems that [this is intended..?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14527)

Is there any known solution for this? There's plenty of literature on making webpack recognize its own project's references, but I haven't been able to find anything that looks like my situation. This is not strictly necessary, but it seems like a stupid and arbitrary limitation that I have to do the whole `../../../../types/filter` in all workspaces except the frontend.